# How can I work out what network account my TFS 2008 instance is using to access Analysis Services?

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

I'm building a new TFS 2010 environment and need to find out what network account my TFS 2008 instance is using to access Sql Server Analysis Services.  How do I find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kilometreage/mileage may vary ...

Two places I checked.

- Computer Management
- Services (order the LogOn Column)

Picture tells a thousand pew-pews...

[image]

HTH ...

Comment: Thanks, found it in the login listed against the TFS services

Comment: what services where those (i tried to look for that but didn't know what to actually find).